# Python Pandas sorting of the middle column when using [groupby]

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python pandas and would like to sort the output by the middle column of the below tables(i have shown the output I am getting and the desired output that i want to get)

I am using the groupby function within pandas to get the output however it is sorting by count column (see below output table), instead i want to sort by the YOB column (please see desired output table)

Also, how do i calculate the mean Year of birth for each country.

```
import pandas as pd

xlpath= "C:/Users/Username/documents/Datafile.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(eval('xlpath'))

y = df.groupby('COUNTRY').YOB.value_counts(ascending=False)

print(y)



Output:
```

[image]

```
Desired Output:
```

[image]

Looking forward to your feedback.

Thanks

Comment: Couple of things that will be required to answer this question properly: 1> Could you please share sample of the source dataset? 2> Do you need to bring the "Country" ascending, "YOB" ascending  in resultset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that you do not care about ordering of "Country" column (as you have not specified that in question), here is one way to achieve the count of per country, per year grouping, keeping years in ascending order:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["Country", "YOB"]).count()
df2 = df2.sort_values(["Country","YOB"], ascending=[True, True])
print(df2)
```

Or in one line:

```
print(df.groupby(["Country", "YOB"]).count().sort_values(["Country","YOB"], ascending=[True, True]))
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways, you can try is sort the dataframe on YOB before you apply groupby.